# Google Maps result and Google Places results are different (XCODE - IPHONE)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps

apparently I am using Google Places API to find the nearest train stations or tram stations. However, the result is not as good as I expected. Many stations are missing in my result.

On the other hand, when I use Google Maps website, the result is good. Very good instead.

So my question is, is there any way to make my application (which use Google Places API) result the same as the result given by Google Maps ?

Thanks...